# Rows reordered in Power Query after Pivoting

Tags: pivot, powerquery

'''= Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1", {{"Start Month", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1", {{"Start Month", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Start Month"]), "Start Month", "Value", List.Sum)'''

This is the M code for the step where I Pivot column "Start Month" on the "Value" column. However, my result reorders a third column, "Measure", alphabetically. I need the rows in the "Measure" column to remain in their previous order.

Are there any solutions to keep the rows in the "Measure" column ordered as they previously were? Thank you!

Sample Data:

[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the month/year column, Sort if desired

Click on the month/year column

Transform ... Pivot columns ....

Values column ... value

Advanced options ... Don't aggregate

Comment: Thanks! I am definitely closer. To clarify my need further, I need the Measure column to repeat the same sequence for each of a fourth column, "Name". So have 52 Measures for each of the Names. When I resort the Index Column, I do indeed end up with the original columns in the original order. But I am now realizing that I need just the Measure column to repeat in the same sub-sequence...if that makes sense. Thanks again for your help, horseyride.

Comment: post sample of data and desired result

Comment: I have added screenshots of the Sample Data and Desired Result in the original question. If you have any suggestions, I am super grateful. And again, the Measures are not in alphabetical order but need to stay ordered that way.